# Cannot locate python module: KV Language, PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, kivy-language

I have an application developed in Kivy which works fine when I execute using a python interpreter. The problem happens when I try to execute after creating an executable using pyinstaller. The .kv file is unable to locate the python modules that it needs. I believe this has something to do with root path configuration of the KV Language but I couldn't find anything to resolve it. "config.py" is the harness/entry file that pyinstaller analyzes. The error occurs in "kv/root_screen.kv" which imports the respective python modules present in "baseclass" folder. Find the screenshot of the error and directory structure below. I have tried executing the files from multiple directories to no effect.

[image]

[image]

Comment: create a [mre] if you need further help

Comment: @alexander I will try and add a minimal reproducible example today. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the solution was to fully uninstall **all** your versions of Python, NOT your code editors, but the Python files.

Usually located in:

```
C:\Users\YOUR PC NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
```

After that go to the official python website:

```
https://www.python.org/downloads/
```

And download your preferred version.

In the install click: Add Python... to Path:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXYmE.png

Then install your modules using PIP.

Comment: Thank you for your response Lexxnl, but I believe my Python is fine, and not that is not the issue here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).